# Eclipse popup background color

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, popup, eclipse-pdt

Where would one go to edit the color of this ugly green popup box in eclipse? I looked everywhere but cannot find it.

My source popup on mouse over background color is correctly set and working correctly as per the screenshot below:

[image]

This popup happens in PDT for instance if you start to type $_ and then stop. It will bring up two popup boxes. The one on the left is white and readible but the secondary one on the right has this weird ugly green color. Forgot to add that this color is the same (stays green) no matter what theme I use. My setup is Kubuntu 13.04 with Eclipse-PDT from the repo's and the Eclipse Color add-in installed. The Colorscheme is Solarized-Dark.

[image: green-popup]

Comment: Are you using a color-theme?

Comment: @SamSu Yes I am, it is Solarized Dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pulled through from the color theme of KDE itself. Very weird, I changed my popup color in KDE to the dark solarized background but I did not change any other color settings. Just resetting the color changed this secondary popup's color to the default of the OS.

Maybe it was trying to do some blending or something else with the custom color...

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> "Source hover background"?

Edit: OK, do you mean the tooltip type popup window? The background color of the View to show Javadoc can be set in Preferences "General -> Appearance -> Colrs and Fonts -> Javadoc view background" but if you mean a tooltip type popup then you might have to set this in your OS.

Preferences > Genreral > Editors > Text Editors

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however it is not that setting. My source popup on mouse over background color is correctly set and working correctly. This popup happens in PDT for instance if you start to type $_ and then stop. It will bring up two popup boxes. The one on the left is white and readible but the  secondary one on the right has this weird ugly green color. Forgot to add that this color is the same (stays green) no matter what theme I use. My setup is Kubuntu 13.04 with Eclipse-PDT from the repo's and the Eclipse Color add-in installed. The Colorscheme is Solarized-Dark.